# Would there be interest in a weekly cartography GIS SE user contest with winning entries features on the main page?

Tags: discussion, questions

Every week Photography SE users are encouraged to submit photos. The rest of the community offers critique which generates interesting discussions. Winning images are then displayed on the main page for 1 week.

Could we do something similar with maps, screen shots of cartographic products or web content?
Each submission (small image with a link to a website/ larger map) would have to be accompanied by a brief description, purpose, etc. Entries with most votes could be featured at the top of the main page similar to how user photos are displayed on Photography SE.

Unlike Photography SE our entries would not only be judged on visual presentation but also idea, content, usefulness, etc. It could generate interesting discussions.

Comment: It's an idea - but some companies would frown on 'their' data begin shown. I have 600 Tranformer FME Workbench would that count (probably not). Though some 'off work' maps might be submitted.

Comment: +1 Given that the [Top Question report](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/494/most-viewed-questions-on-gis-se) showed that [Examples of Beautiful Maps](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/examples-of-beautiful-maps) is the most viewed question, this is an excellent idea.

Comment: I think the idea is great, but I think that a week is a bit fast for a typical GIS workflow.  Yes, we can all slap some layers and map elements onto a map in an hour, but most of us would not be terribly proud of the results.  Photographers, on the other hand, can take and edit several snazzy pictures in the same amount of time.  So, the timeframe might need to be expanded.

Comment: This is a great idea. It would be nice to feature some of the beautiful maps which are being produced, to show that you don't need a Table of Contents with 15 grouped layers to make a map these days

Answer (score 5):

This might be a great idea, if the content could be broadened.  I have been using GIS for a very long time, but I rarely make "maps", perhaps taking out the work "cartography" out of your question line would broaden the appeal.  This might open it up to other things GISie (eg. algorithm implementations, data sources etc etc)

Comment: You need some kind of entry criteria if you want to make judgments.  How could you say, "This algorithm is better than that map"?  Maybe we could rotate categories.  Dedicate one week to Cartography and another to algorithms and whatever else can be thought of.